# htaccess wildcard redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm updating a website and need some help with a wildcard 301 redirect, in this case for all 50 US states.

The old format is like this:

> http://www.example.com/find-a-location/find-a-location/usa/alabama/

The new format is like this:

> http://www.example.com/location_category/alabama/

I believe I could do it by listing all 50 lines with a redirect 301. However, I'm looking to do it in just 1 line if possible.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a generic rule like this:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/find-a-location/find-a-location/usa/([^/]+)/?$ /location_category/$1/
```

Regex `([^/]+)` will capture state name in `$1` and target will use reference of `$1` as `/location_category/$1/`.

Comment: Yes, I did already.  I don't have enough points yet for it to show, but it will.

Comment: No, to accept an answer you don't need 15 reps. You just need to click on **tick mark on top-left of my answer** and it will turn green. This will also give you 2 points.